# JS\jquery как отправить значения нескольких чекбоксов

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

нужно в зависимости от выбранных чекбоксов отображать те или иные элементы. как сделать отправку состояния чекбоксов при изменении любого из них и как сохранить?

пока есть такой кошмар

```
$smena_plan = ($_POST['smena_plan'] == 'checked') ? NULL : 'checked';
$smena_fact = ($_POST['smena_fact'] == 'checked') ? NULL : 'checked';
$day_plan = ($_POST['day_plan'] == 'checked') ? NULL : 'checked';
$day_fact = ($_POST['day_fact'] == 'checked') ? NULL : 'checked';
$month_plan = ($_POST['month_plan'] == 'checked') ? NULL : 'checked';
$month_fact = ($_POST['month_fact'] == 'checked') ? NULL : 'checked';

<form name="upsert" id ="myForm" method="POST">
    <label ><input type="checkbox" id="smena_plan" name="smena_plan" <?= $smena_plan ?>/> Смена(план)</label>
    <label ><input type="checkbox" id="smena_fact" <?= $smena_fact ?>/> Смена(факт)</label>
    <label ><input type="checkbox" id="day_plan" <?= $day_plan ?>/> Сутки(план)</label>
    <label ><input type="checkbox" id="day_fact" <?= $day_fact ?>/> Сутки(факт)</label>
    <label ><input type="checkbox" id="month_plan" <?= $month_plan ?>/> Месяц(план)</label>
    <label ><input type="checkbox" id="month_fact" <?= $month_fact ?>/> Месяц(факт)</label>
</div>
<input name="smena_plan" type="hidden" value="<?= $smena_plan ?>">
<input name="smena_fact" type="hidden" value="<?= $smena_fact?>">
<input name="day_plan" type="hidden" value="<?= $day_plan ?>">
<input name="day_fact" type="hidden" value="<?= $day_fact ?>">
<input name="month_plan" type="hidden" value="<?= $month_plan ?>">
<input name="month_fact" type="hidden" value="<?= $month_fact ?>">
</form>
<script>
        $("input:checkbox").change(function () {
            $('#myForm').submit();
        });

    });
</script>
```

но при выборке любого получается что выбираются все

идея такая - предположим выбран 1 чекбокс, страница перезагружается появляется столбик, выбирается 2 чекбокс страница перезагружается еще 1 столбик. 1ый при этом не пропадает. страница помнит какие чеки выбраны

Comment: попробуй так `if (isset($_POST['smena_plan'])) { $smena_plan = $_POST['smena_plan']; } else { $smena_plan = ''; }`

Comment: оно от этого отправлять все чекбоксы не перестанет

Comment: тогда задай вопрос по русски пожалуйста

Comment: если страшненько то можно так https://gist.github.com/des1roer/b7618371587d3dff1701

Comment: в таком случае я бы конструировал форму динамически на клиенте и отправлял запрос на сервер аяксом и получив нужный столбик обновил DOM документа.

Comment: теперь более понятно, так и выводи тогда столбик `if ( $smena_plan != '') { тут твой столбик }`

Comment: @Dmitry OnGamer полностью поддерживаю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задавайте для чекбоксов одинаковое имя. При выборе некскольких вариантов значением поля будут выбранные значения, разделенные запятыми. Кроме-того если у вас есть несколько однотипных полей, их стОит формировать и обрабатывать в цикле, предварительно задав в массиве список значений и названий.

В вашем случае можно поступить так:

```
<form name="upsert" id ="myForm" method="POST">
<div>
<?php
$options = array(
    'smena_plan' => 'Смена(план)',
    'smena_fact' => 'Смена(факт)',
    'day_plan'   => 'Сутки(план)',
    'day_fact'   => 'Сутки(факт)',
    'month_plan' => 'Месяц(план)',
    'month_fact' => 'Месяц(факт)',
);
$checkedOptions = isset($_POST['options']) ? explode(',', $_POST['options']) : array();
foreach ($options as $value => $caption) {
    $checked = in_array($value, $checkedOptions) ? ' checked="checked"' : '';
?>
    <label><input type="checkbox" id="smena_plan" name="smena_plan"<?php echo $checked ?>/>
    <?php echo $caption; ?>
    </label>
<?php
} 
?>
</div>
</form>
<script>
    $("input:checkbox").change(function () {
        $('#myForm').get(0).submit();
    });
</script>
```